# Dynamically take ports from squid.conf files and put them to json file using bash

Tags: json, bash

I have a task where I need to take ports from multiple configuration squid files and put them to json file.

So far I was able to do it following the next way:

```
echo -n "{ \"data\":" > test.json
echo -n "  [" >> test.json

sqcur=0
sqtotal=`ls /etc/squid?.conf | wc -l`
tcp_ports=$(grep "port" /etc/squid?.conf |awk '{print $2}' |sed 's|.*[0-9]*\:||g'|sort|uniq|xargs)

for squidconf in `ls /etc/squid?.conf`; do
  let "sqcur+=1" > /dev/null
  squidident=`echo $squidconf | sed 's/.*\///' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'`  
  if [ $sqcur -lt $sqtotal ]; then
    echo -n "    { \"{#SQPROC}\": \"/usr/local/squid/bin/squid\", \"{#SQPROC_IDENT}\": \"${squidident}\", \"{#SQPROC_ARGS}\": \"-D -C -F -f ${squidconf}\", \"{#SQPROC_PORT}\": \"${tcp_ports}\", \"{#SQPROC_CONF}\": \"${squidconf}\" }," >> test.json
  else
    echo -n "    { \"{#SQPROC}\": \"/usr/local/squid/bin/squid\", \"{#SQPROC_IDENT}\": \"${squidident}\", \"{#SQPROC_ARGS}\": \"-D -C -F -f ${squidconf}\", \"{#SQPROC_PORT}\": \"${tcp_ports}\", \"{#SQPROC_CONF}\": \"${squidconf}\" }" >> test.json  
  fi
done

echo -n "  ]" >> test.json
echo "}" >> test.json
```

The output will be the next:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "{#SQPROC}": "/usr/local/squid/bin/squid",
            "{#SQPROC_IDENT}": "squid1",
            "{#SQPROC_ARGS}": "-D -C -F -f /etc/squid1.conf",
            "{#SQPROC_PORT}": "1111 2222 3333 4444",
            "{#SQPROC_CONF}": "/etc/squid1.conf"
        },
        {
            "{#SQPROC}": "/usr/local/squid/bin/squid",
            "{#SQPROC_IDENT}": "squid2",
            "{#SQPROC_ARGS}": "-D -C -F -f /etc/squid2.conf",
            "{#SQPROC_PORT}": "1111 2222 3333 4444",
            "{#SQPROC_CONF}": "/etc/squid2.conf"
        },
        {
            "{#SQPROC}": "/usr/local/squid/bin/squid",
            "{#SQPROC_IDENT}": "squid3",
            "{#SQPROC_ARGS}": "-D -C -F -f /etc/squid3.conf",
            "{#SQPROC_PORT}": "1111 2222 3333 4444",
            "{#SQPROC_CONF}": "/etc/squid3.conf"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I need that ports which are defined in each of config files will be associated in json file only with that config file where they are defined.

Eg 1111 and 2222 are defined in squid1.conf, so the output of json will must be the next:

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "{#SQPROC}": "/usr/local/squid/bin/squid",
                "{#SQPROC_IDENT}": "squid1",
                "{#SQPROC_ARGS}": "-D -C -F -f /etc/squid1.conf",
                "{#SQPROC_PORT}": "1111 2222",
                "{#SQPROC_CONF}": "/etc/squid1.conf"
            },
```

and so on for the rest of config files.

Could you please help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the definition of `tcp_ports` inside the loop,
and run it only on the current config file:

```
for squidconf in `ls /etc/squid?.conf`; do
  let "sqcur+=1" > /dev/null
  squidident=`echo $squidconf | sed 's/.*\///' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'`  
  tcp_ports=$(grep "port" $squidconf |awk '{print $2}' |sed 's|.*[0-9]*\:||g'|sort|uniq|xargs)
  if [ $sqcur -lt $sqtotal ]; then
    echo -n "    { \"{#SQPROC}\": \"/usr/local/squid/bin/squid\", \"{#SQPROC_IDENT}\": \"${squidident}\", \"{#SQPROC_ARGS}\": \"-D -C -F -f ${squidconf}\", \"{#SQPROC_PORT}\": \"${tcp_ports}\", \"{#SQPROC_CONF}\": \"${squidconf}\" }," >> test.json
  else
    echo -n "    { \"{#SQPROC}\": \"/usr/local/squid/bin/squid\", \"{#SQPROC_IDENT}\": \"${squidident}\", \"{#SQPROC_ARGS}\": \"-D -C -F -f ${squidconf}\", \"{#SQPROC_PORT}\": \"${tcp_ports}\", \"{#SQPROC_CONF}\": \"${squidconf}\" }" >> test.json  
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am really a bit stupid that missed it in script.